# Understanding the benefits of scipy.spatial.distance.pdist

Tags: python, matrix

I need to compute the cosine distance between every two rows of a matrix.
I needed a single row each time, so my naive implementation was:

```
        for Id1 in range(m.shape[0]):
        distance = [scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(m[Id1,],m[Id2,]) for Id2 in range(m.shape[0])]
```

It turns out the the naive implementation requires about 4 seconds for 407*53 matrix.

Although i don't want the full matrix, i tried:

```
pairwiseDistance = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(m,metric = 'cosine')
```

It requires just 0.004 seconds (!)

I expected a small linear improvement (i need just half of the matrix, the process can be done in parallel etc.). What is the reason that the improvement is so significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a string to `pdist` to use one of its predefined metrics, it uses a version written in C, which is much faster than calling the Python one.  This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist).

Even using `pdist` with a Python function might be somewhat faster than using a list comprehension, since `pdist` can still do the looping and allocate the result array in C.

Comment: Code implemented in c can run 1000 faster than code written in python?

Comment: @Guys: In some cases, yes.